# Do lifetime parameters in `*(&'a mut self)` methods confuse the BorrowChecker?

Tags: rust

The following example does not compile as long as `'a` is used in `&'a mut self`:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    a: &'a u64,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn mutate_internal(&'a mut self) {}

    fn mutate(&'a mut self) {
        self.mutate_internal();
        self.mutate_internal(); // <- This call fails the borrow-check
    }
}
```

The compiler surprised me with the following error message:

```
tests/lang.rs:1116:13: 1116:17 error: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
tests/lang.rs:1116             self.mutate_internal();
                               ^~~~
tests/lang.rs:1115:13: 1115:17 note: previous borrow of `*self` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `*self` until the borrow ends
tests/lang.rs:1115             self.mutate_internal();
                               ^~~~
tests/lang.rs:1117:10: 1117:10 note: previous borrow ends here
tests/lang.rs:1114         fn mutate(&'a mut self) {
tests/lang.rs:1115             self.mutate_internal();
tests/lang.rs:1116             self.mutate_internal();
tests/lang.rs:1117         }
                           ^
```

**Can you explain why that is ?** Please note that the issue goes away if `&'a mut self` becomes `&mut self`.

#### Meta

```
✗ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (e2fa53e59 2015-03-20) (built 2015-03-20)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you drop the `'a` named lifetime in `mutate_internal`, what you get is a fresh (anonymous) lifetime parameter, not `'a`. I.e. you get something equivalent to:

```
fn mutate_internal<'b>(&'b mut self) {}
```

this means that self is borrowed until `mutate_internal` is done, but no longer than that. That's why the second call to `mutate_internal` compiles.

By contrast, with `fn mutate_internal(&'a mut self) {}` you're telling the compiler that self will be borrowed as long as `'a` (which is the entire lifetime of `Foo`). That's why the second `mutate_internal` can't be called